# Note 8 dies when battery is drained completely

Tags: samsung, battery, unbricking, samsung-galaxy-note-8

the samsung galaxy note 8 dies when battery is drained completely and it wont start or charge unless the battery is pulled and charged and pushed back again.
Why this happens and is there any solution for it ?

Comment: Even if the device seems to be off you can try a hard power off (press power button for more than 10 seconds) to really shut if off.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a Note 8, it MAY still be covered by a warranty. If so, take the phone to the store you bought it, they should look it up for you, and if it needs any repair they will take care of it, since as far as I can tell it's not your fault.